# JobLauncherCommandLineRunner doesn't exit on Job Completion

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm not sure if I'm using `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` correctly. I'm developing a batch job that will be invoked via command line, run to completion, and then stop. It takes 1 argument from the command line and I am using:

- spring-boot 1.5.9
- spring-batch 3.0.8

When I invoke this via the command line, for example:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=solr,cassandra -Dspring.config.location=/path/to/job.yml -jar myjob.jar jobParam=/path/to/file.csv
```

The application seems to run "forever" (at least beyond when the job finishes). Is there a configuration somewhere to shut down the context on job completion?

Currently my `main` is very simple and I'd like to keep it that way. But maybe I need custom logic here to stop the context once the job completes?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyJob.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**tldr;**
Put `SpringApplication.exit(context);` after your `SpringApplication.run` command in your `main` method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(NingesterApplication.class, args);
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context));
    }
}
```

---

Figured it out. There are a few key things to understand:

- [BatchAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.html) automatically registers an [ExitCodeGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ExitCodeGenerator.html) to the application context for [JobExecutionEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/JobExecutionEvent.html)s.
- This `ExitCodeGenerator` (specifically it is a [JobExecutionExitCodeGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/JobExecutionExitCodeGenerator.html)) will collect the [BatchStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/BatchStatus.html) from every `JobExecution` linked to `JobExecutionEvent`s.
- The [JobLauncherCommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.html) publishes a `JobExecutionEvent` for every job it executes.
- The `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` launches job as part of the application context startup

Therefore, the batch job will run to completion before `SpringApplication.run(MyJob.class, args);` returns the application context (because the job is part of the context startup).

So, all I need to do is add one more line to my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyJob {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJob.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(NingesterApplication.class, args);
        // The batch job has finished by this point because the 
        //   ApplicationContext is not 'ready' until the job is finished
        // Also, use System.exit to force the Java process to finish with the exit code returned from the Spring App
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context));
    }
}
```

Then, make sure you use `System.exit()` to make sure the application will exit with an exit code that matches the `BatchStatus` ordinal value.

---

Side note: The log is a little misleading because I see

1. Job Launched
2. Job Finished
3. Context Started
4. Context Closing.

But functionally it works:

```
2018-01-18 12:47:58.363  INFO 1504 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myjob]] launched with the following parameters: [{jobParam=/path/to/file.csv}]
2018-01-18 12:47:58.399  INFO 1504 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2018-01-18 12:50:12.347  INFO 1504 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myjob]] completed with the following parameters: [{jobParam=/path/to/file.csv}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2018-01-18 12:50:12.349  INFO 1504 --- [           main] g.n.j.n.ningester.NingesterApplication   : Started NingesterApplication in 136.813 seconds (JVM running for 137.195)
2018-01-18 12:50:12.350  INFO 1504 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@24313fcc: startup date [Thu Jan 18 12:47:55 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```